# Apps for websites fails with sideloading unless in Developer Mode

Tags: uwp, sideloading

I have written a UWP app which links to a website using an app URI handler (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/web-to-app-linking).
The app is signed with a an in-house certificate (NOT self signed) and works fine if run manually using sideloading.
However the URI handling will ONLY work if Developer mode is turned on.
If Developer mode is not turned on Edge is launched instead of the app when the URL is accessed.
The URL is not a site I control so there is no scope for adding a JSON file as mentioned in the docs.
Should this scenario work in non-Developer mode?

Answer (score 0):

> Should this scenario work in non-Developer mode?

I'm afraid, you could not install sideload app within non-Developer mode in the **old OS version**, and it is by design. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/sideload-apps-in-windows-10#how-do-i-sideload-an-app-on-desktop) is document. But if your Windows Insider Build 18956, sideloading is enabled by default. **Now, you can deploy a signed package onto a device without a special configuration.**  So please update your OS to latest version.

Update 1

For install the sideload from website, please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/installing-windows10-apps-web#signing-the-app-package), *If a third party certificate is used, the user will need to have their device in either sideload or developer mode to install and run your app.*

Comment: This is on Windows 10 2004 (build 19041.867)

Comment: I have tested in my environment(2004), it could install the sideload app in non-developer model.

Comment: yes, it installs and runs fine in non-developer mode. It is the web association that does not work. As the question says - it works fine when not in developer mode, but the web association will only work when in developer mode

Comment: Please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/installing-windows10-apps-web#signing-the-app-package), *If a third party certificate is used, the user will need to have their device in either sideload or developer mode to install and run your app.*

Comment: The device is in sideload mode

Comment: Could you mind show the setting detail with screenshot?